# Como criar uma árvore com n filhos por nó?

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Gostaria de saber como implementar uma árvore em que cada nó possa ter *n* filhos?

Como no exemplo abaixo: [image: diagrama da árvore]

Só que no caso os nós seriam uma instância de uma classe.

**EDITADO**

Eu estou tentando fazer isso com um `ArrayList`, mas não estou entendendo como inserir um `ArrayList` dentro de um `ArrayList` de forma recursiva ou interativa mesmo pois a árvore não tem limite definido.

Exemplo: Como inserir e pegar o valor 7? Tipo vai ter o `ArrayList` pro no raiz (8) e vai ter o `ArrayList` pro primeiro nó do nó raiz (o 4).

Comment: Comece com isso: `public class No { private List<No> nos; /* ... */ }`.

Comment: Array se possui um limite. Mas se tiver tratando de Arvore Trie ou Patricia, você utilize uma lista encadeada, com o pai apontando para o primeiro filho.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para exemplificar melhor minha dúvida.

Answer (score 4):

> Eu estou tentando fazer isso com um `ArrayList`, mas não estou entendendo como inserir um `ArrayList` dentro de um `ArrayList` de forma recursiva ou interativa mesmo pois a árvore não tem limite definido.

Não é isso que você deveria fazer. Isso é um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132).

Java é uma linguagem orientada a objetos. Manter listas recursivas de números não é uma forma orientada a objetos de atacar o seu problema. Isso significa que essa abordagem provavelmente não vai funcionar. Se você conseguir fazer funcionar, o resultado será uma baita gambiarra.

A melhor forma seria ver quais são os objetos envolvidos nisso:

1. Você tem uma `Arvore`.
2. A `Arvore` tem um `No` raiz.
3. Cada `No` pode ter vários outros `No`s abaixo dele.
4. Cada `No` guarda um número inteiro.

Transformando esses quatro requisitos em código:

```
public class Arvore {
    private No raiz;
}
```

```
import java.util.List;

public class No {
    private int conteudo;
    private List<No> filhos;
}
```

Ok, agora que temos a estrutura geral das nossas classes, vamos definir alguns métodos e construtores:

```
public class Arvore {
    private No raiz;

    public Arvore(int conteudoRaiz) {
        this.raiz = new No(conteudoRaiz);
    }

    public No getRaiz() {
        return raiz;
    }

    public No buscar(int procurado) {
        raiz.buscar(procurado);
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class No {
    private int conteudo;
    private List<No> filhos;

    public No(int conteudo) {
        this.filhos = new ArrayList<>();
        this.conteudo = conteudo;
    }

    public No acrescentarFilho(int conteudoFilho) {
        No n = new No(conteudoFilho);
        filhos.add(n);
        return n;
    }

    public int getConteudo() {
        return conteudo;
    }

    public List<No> getFilhos() {
        return filhos;
    }

    public No buscar(int procurado) {
        if (procurado == conteudo) return this;
        for (No filho : filhos) {
            No achou = filho.buscar(procurado);
            if (achou != null) return achou;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Você pode ir acrescentando outros métodos para realizar os trabalhos que deseja, mas a questão aqui é que você tem que ter bem definido o que cada coisa é. Dizer que uma árvore **é** uma lista ou que um nó de uma árvore **é** uma lista apenas deixa as coisas complicadas e confusas e provavelmente não vai funcionar. O ideal é dizer que a árvore **tem** um nó raiz, que um nó **tem** uma lista de outros nós. Observe que o verbo é importante: o conceito se **ser** e **ter** muda completamente a forma como você vai estruturar o seu código.